# Jquery создать квадратики в блоке?

Tags: jquery

Как можно с помощью jquery заполнить квадратиками допустим:
20*20 любой блок по высоте + ширине? Знаю что надо использовать циклы, но как пока не могу додумать, помогите решить вопрос если сталкивались с таким)

Comment: Чем background-image не угодил?

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Участники сообщества не занимаются написанием кода по заявкам, а только помогают решить **конкретные** проблемы, связанные с **имеющимся** кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто побаловался, как раз решение вашей задачи на js

```js
$(function() {
  var div = $('.div');
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        div.append('<div></div>');
        div.find('div:last').css('backgroundColor', color());
      }, 50 * i);
    })(i)
  }

  function color() {
    var arr = ["#66FF99", "#33FF99", "#00FF99", "#33CC66", "#00CC66"];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[rand];
  }
});
```

```css
div.div {
  width: 100px;
}
div.div > div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
```